# Unit test says function was called, but console.logs are not showing up

Tags: unit-testing, parse-platform, jasmine

I have a function inside another function that is supposedly getting called, according to my `expect(Parse.User.Login).toHaveBeenCalled()` line, but there are some console statements inside the callback to that which aren't showing up.

Is there some type of dependency I'm missing on my unit test causing the callback not to have called? I think it is getting to the server, because it tells me I need a `Parse.initialize` with the application keys if that's not present.

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just occurred to me, maybe that's something in Parse.js telling me I need the Parse.initialize(keys,keys). I changed the parse keys to nonsense, and its not telling me they're wrong, so it must be that parse isn't being touched at all. No request is being sent to the server.

I've been putting up a few questions about this, but now I guess this can't be done with Karma-jasmine -- at least the way the app is set up right now. It's depending on a web service to give the errors, instead of having an angular directive set up up front to detect the errors in the fields beforehand.

I'm a newbie at this obviously, or I would have recognized this sooner:

This type of testing, where you are depending on responses from the server and that's that, should be delegated to E2E tests.

Meaning, here what am I supposed to test that wouldn't be just hardcoding the desired response right into the jasmine Spy? What would that do to just set the rootScope to a user attribute? Maybe, if `state.go` changed the view to another page, and then acted on the `$rootScope` data, this would make sense. But for now, there's no point. I'm not designing the next step, nor do I know what it is at the moment, so I can only sit back.